# Bash Output different from command line

Tags: bash

I have tried all kinds of filters using grep to try and solve this but just cannot crack it.

```
cpumem="$(ps aux | grep -v 'grep' | grep 'firefox-bin' | awk '{printf $3 "\t" $4}'
```

I am extracting the CPU and Memory usage for a process and when I run it from the command line, I get the 2 fields outputted correctly:

```
ps aux | grep -v 'grep' | grep 'firefox-bin' | awk '{printf $3 "\t" $4}'
> 1.1 4.4
```

but the same command executed from within the bash script produces this:

```
cpumem="$(ps aux | grep -v 'grep' | grep 'firefox-bin' | awk '{printf $3 "\t" $4}')"
echo -e cpumem
> 1.1 4.40.0 0.10.0 0.0
```

I am guessing that it is picking up 3 records, but I just don't know where from.

I am filtering out any other grep processes by using grep -v 'grep', can someone offer any suggestions or a more reliable way ??

Comment: You can eliminate the need for the first `grep` by changing the second one to `grep '[f]irefox-bin'`; it's pattern that won't match itself. Also, just replace the "\t" with a comma, as the tab will be converted to a single space anyway after it is captured by `$( ... )`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have 3 records because 3 firefox are running (or one is running, and it is threading itself).

You can avoid the grep hazzle by giving `ps` and option to select the processes. E.g. the `-C` to select processes by name. With `ps -C firefox-bin` you get only the firefox processes. But this does not help at all, when there is more than one process.

(You can also use the ps option to output only the columns you want, so your line would be like

```
ps -C less --no-headers -o %cpu,%mem
```

).

For the triple-record you must come up with a solution, what should happen, where more than one is running. In a multiuser environment with programms that are threading there can always be situations where you have more than one process of a kind. There are many possible solution where none can help you, as you dont say, way you are going to do with it. One can think of solutions like selecting only from one user, and only the one with the lowest pid, or the process-leader in case of groups, to change the enclosing bash-script to use a loop to handle the multiple values or make it working somehow different when ps returns multiple results.

Comment: Thanks so much to all of you, there is only ever 1 instance of firefox running. I used the following: cpumem=$(ps -C $PROC --no-headers -o %cpu,%mem) which seems to work now. Thanks again.

Comment: Note that `-C` has a different meaning in the BSD version of `ps`.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to reproduce the problem, but to help you debug, try print $11 in your awk command, that will tell you what process it is talking about

cpumem="$(ps aux | grep -v 'grep' | grep 'firefox-bin' | awk '{printf $3 "\t" $4 "\t" $11 "\n"}')"
echo -e cpumem

Answer (score 0):

It's actually an easy fix for the output display; In your `echo` statement, wrap the variable in double-quotes:

```
echo -e "$cpumem"
```

Without using double-quotes, newlines are not preserved by converting them to single-spaces (or empty values). With quotes, the original text of the variable is preserved when outputted.

If your output contains multiple processes (i.e. - multiple lines), that means your `grep` actually matched multiple lines. There's a chance a child-process is running for `firefox-bin`, maybe a plugin/container? With `ps aux`, the `11th` column will tell you what the actual process is, so you can update your `awk` to be the following (for debugging):

```
awk '{printf $3 "\t" $4 "\t" $11}'
```